# How to convert Retrofit response to JsonObject

Tags: android, retrofit

Retrofit JSON Response:

```
{
 "data": [{
        "id": 1224410,
        "amount": "900200.00",
        "meta": {
            "referenceId": "referenceId","time": "2017-11-01T15:42:26Z","type": "send"
        }
    }],
"version": "v2"
}
```

These are model structures:

```
public class MyOject {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int mId;
    @SerializedName("amount")
    private double mAmount;
    @SerializedName("meta")
    private JSONObject mMeta;
}
```

I always get `null` in the `mMeta` variable

Update code
class Wrapper using to parse response from JSONObject:

```
public class ResponseWrapper<DataType> {
    @SerializedName("data")
    private DataType mData;
    @SerializedName("version")
    private String mVersion;
}
```

This is Callback. I use it to specify the type of data to receive.

```
public class CallbackWithData<T> implements Callback<ResponseWrapper<T>> {
    @Override
    public final void success(ResponseWrapper<T> data, Response response) {
        this.success(data.getData(), data.getVersion());
    }
    public abstract void success(T data, String version);
}
```

This is the API I use, which defines the desired object.

```
 @GET("/transaction")
 void listTransactions(@Header(Constants.Header.LOGIN_SECRET) String loginSecret, CallbackWithData<List<MyObject>> callback);
```

Comment: put the code when you are parsing the data

Comment: @diegoveloper I using `Retrofit` and default `GsonConverter` to parsing response.

Comment: why are you using double on mAmount if your json is a String value

Comment: Using `RestAdapter.Builder restBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))` and auto parsing to `MyObject` The values I have declared through the annotation

Comment: Could you put the retrofit interface ?

Comment: It is automatically through GsonConverter, I absolutely can not intervene

Comment: are you receiving a List<MyObject> or MyObject? we need the code

Comment: Why don't you use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  ? Just select JSON and GSON as source type and annotation style.

Comment: @diegoveloper Not necessary, Previously I created an object and instead of `JSONObject` would be the object I specified. Even the list runs great.

Comment: we need to see the code man , put how are you calling retrofit callback

Comment: @AnshulTyagi Because I do not know for sure what the `meta` would be. And I would like to get all the information if yes.

Comment: Ok. Then use object and check instance at run time when you want to use that.

Comment: @diegoveloper I have updated the code above. Do not know what it is that you need?

Comment: could you put the logcat with the error?

Comment: No errors, Other variables are valid, Only the `mMeta` variable is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HashMap instead of JSONObject :

```
    @SerializedName("meta")
    private HashMap mMeta;
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: @diegoveloper Can you explain little more.How it was work completely

Comment: so looks like gson can't deserialize json object into JSONObject class, then the HashMap is a valid option